# Java ZipFile api fails to extract large files

Tags: java, zip, zipinputstream

I am reading a large zip file (above 2.5GB). When i try to decompress a file above 2.5GB, I get an exeption

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:163)
```

This error doesnot occur when I use ZipInputStream instead of ZipFile. Why is this behaviour in ZipFile api.

Comment: Is this complete stack trace ?

Comment: added full stack trace

Comment: @AnirbanChakrabarti Can you add some code so we can troubleshoot this?